# how to get rid of duplicate date in excel line chart?

Tags: excel, linechart

I am using excel track my stock PnL. both 3/1 and 3/2 I have 2 trades. in the line chart, I only want to use the last data of the day.

```
date   return
3/1/19  2%
3/1/19  1%
3/2/19  3%
3/2/19  4.5%
3/3/19  6%
```

this is what I want to show on the line chart.  how do I do that?

```
date   return
3/1/19  1%
3/2/19  4.5%
3/3/19  6%
```

Answer (score 2):

Since charts ignore `#N/A` errors, you can just add another column which produces a `#N/A` if that date already exists and point your chart to that column instead.

The simple formula, for ordered data, would be something like this

```
=IF(A2=A3,NA(),B2)
```

If your data isn't ordered by date then you can use this formula

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)=COUNTIF($A$2:$A$6,A2),B2,NA())
```

This is the setup I was using:

[image]

Comment: thank you. but I need data from the last trade of the day. for example, 3/1 I have 2 trades, first one I made 2%, second one it dropped back to 1%. I wan to get 1% for 3/1.

Comment: @qinking126, that's easily remedied, I'll update the answer

Comment: @qinking126, see amended formulas :)